# Vue router in sub folder config in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a web app built with laravel in example.com and then I created a new Vue app and placed in `/public/wt` with vue router history mode. I can access my vue application in `example.com/wt` and if not logged in redirected to `example.com/wt/login`, but when i access directly the login url it will be internal server error.
Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /wt/
  RewriteRule ^\wt\index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /wt/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

what id probably wrong and what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

in vue.config.js file add this line to module.exports

```
  publicPath:'/wt/',
```

this is htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /wt/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

this is router config

```
let router = new Router({
    base: '/wt',
    mode: 'history', // https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    scrollBehavior: () => ({y: 0}),
    routes: configRoutes(),
});
```

Comment: I've configured like that, but the problem is i placed the dis inside laravel's public dir, so i think it conflicted with laravel route